How would I disconnect the drain pipe from the drain pan under the washing machine?
I'm trying to access my washing machine's filter (access is behind the back panel) , but I can't move the drain pan with this being in place.
Does anyone know how to remove one of these?

https://imgur.com/a/oWbQ9pr
Or should I just try to lift the washing machine out of the drain pan?

what is the model

Typically that black thing is a nut that's threaded onto the white pipe (there should be a rubber gasket too).  Are there any flats on it?  You may need to lift the washer out of the pan to get access.

Thanks, I think most people are saying to remove the washer from the pan. And If I'm doing that, I might as well leave the pan/pipe where it is.

@Kev yes, if you only need access to the back of the washer, you shouldn't even bother with the drain, assuming it's not leaking.  Greg's answer below gives you a good way to get the washer forward so you can access behind it.

Yeah, it's going to be tough to disconnect that drain line without breaking anything while the washer remains in place -- and even more difficult to reconnect it without cross-threading.
If you're working alone or otherwise unable to easily lift the washer out of the pan, tip the washer alternating directions and place wood blocks beneath it until the washer's feet are higher than the pan. Then you can rotate or slide the washer over the walls of the pan to gain access for your repair.

I'll take a look at what's in the garage and give it a go. Thank you.

Good description of how to get the washer out of the pan without doing really heavy lifting.
